# Flatten sphere to a cookie shape

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm sure I'm just missing something very simple, but I can't manage to flatten both halves of a sphere different amounts like a cookie.

I've thought of scaling the vertices on a single axis, but that scales them to the center of the selection, not to the center of the object.

Does anyone know what obvious thing I'm missing?

Comment: I think all you need to do is to scale the sphere in the Z axis when in object mode.
Just make sure your transform pivot point is set to median, and transform orientation is set to Global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work on a sphere with the 3D cursor at its center.  Change the Transform Pivot Point to 3D cursor:

[image]

Select all the vertices on or below the 3D cursor on the Z axis, then Scale to 0 on the Z axis only, S Z 0 :

[image]

Select all the vertices above the 3D cursor on the Z axis, then Scale on the Z axis only by however much you need, S Z move your mouse towards the 3D cursor :

[image]

Tip:  When you're done change the Transform Pivot Point back to what you usually have it on (the default is Median Point).

Comment: Thanks! I honestly never thought of using the transform pivot point. I'll wait for some other answers before accepting yours, though.

Comment: Okay, it's been about a week.  If I've answered your question I'd appreciate it if you'd click the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that - I totally forgot.